# IIS Express extremely slow start while debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, iis-express

I am working on a C# MVC project that is set up to run using IIS Express. I am using Rider as my IDE and every time i start the project using the "Run" option it starts up quickly without any issues. However, when starting the project using the "Debug" option the startup is extremely slow 95% of the time - and by extremely slow i mean up to 10 minutes. The build process itself is very quick and I have narrowed down the issue to IIS. I also tried running the project via Visual Studio with the same effect.

Some of the modules that are loaded by IIS load extremely slow - not always the same ones, but the usual culprits are:

```
FeatureToggle.dll
CsQuery.dll
System.Web.Http.OData.dll
```

I have read almost every single question relating to slow startups on google with no effect.
I have tried reinstalling, changing configuration, clearing cache among others.

The issue has been here since I received the laptop. My co-workers are using the same laptops and have no issues at all.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: "The issue has been here since I received the laptop. My co-workers are using the same laptops and have no issues at all." That means no matter who is going to help, he/she needs to access this machine to dig further. Thus, don't waste anyone's time here on Stack Overflow, contact JetBrains support and let them take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your incredibly constructive comment. I only mentioned that the issue was there since I received the laptop to highlight that I made no changes. Also, as I wrote in the question, the issue is with IIS so I have no reason to contact JetBrains.

Comment: With so many things (like Rider) installed on it, "I made no changes" is not likely to be true (changes can happen without you noticing). Like I said, anyone wanting to help will need to access this machine directly, so either JetBrains or Microsoft support team should be your best resource at this moment who have the skills to analyze such typical performance issues and find the solutions.

Comment: Come on, with that logic only people with a clean windows install would be able to ask question on stack overflow. Either way, problem solved. It was a software issue after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it by following the instructions from [this link](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/q393794/devexpress-components-tent-to-connect-to-internet-before-starting)

Some assemblies are signed with the Microsoft digital certificate and the delay occurs due to the runtime attempt to verify the certificate.

Add the following to your configuration file:

```
<configuration>  
    <runtime>  
        <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>  
    </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: FYI According to Microsoft site "In the .NET Framework 4 and later, this element has no effect on assembly load times."  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/generatepublisherevidence-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: this works now is really fast